# How can I change default timezone in Liferay Portal 5.2+

Tags: java, time, timezone, liferay

I'm having an issue using Liferay Portal Community 5.2.3 according to timezones and time offsets.  In windows, it seems to work correctly (GMT+2 Madrid picked auto), but when I install in Linux server, timezone gets stuck to UTC (GMT).

I've no system-ext.properties, so default is UTC, but then... how it works on Windows?

In administration->system properties I get UTC for timezone on both installations

What am I doing wrong?

And another question.  If i set timezone to GMT+2 (CEST), what happens when daylight saving is "removed" (CET)?¿  Do I have to specify timezone as "Europe/Madrid" or as "GMT+2"?  Does it change automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Tomás García

Comment: Notice that current system time/timezone are correct on both installations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass that as a system property when starting Liferay.

Assuming you are using the Tomcat bundle, check out the file `bin\setenv.bat` on Windows or `bin/setenv.sh` on Linux.

The Liferay default package contains the parameter

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT
```

in the set JAVA_OPTS line.

Just change that to the your timezone, e.g.

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid
```

Europe/Madrid will correctly deal with DST if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Uhm... in windows installation -Duser.timezone is omitted so I suppose it gets default system timezone.  In linux timezone is hardcoded to UTC.

I'll try it as soon as I can.  Thanks for fast reply!

Comment: but the main point here is that once the setting is configured in both environments, you will always get consistent behaviour.