# Get date in current timezone in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

I have been searching over the net from past few hours to get the  datetime in my system timezone.

When I use `calendar.getTimezone.getDefaultName()`it always returns me `GMT`. Ideally it should return my current timezone, which is `IST`.

I am trying to convert this string "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00", which is in `GMT` to my timezone datetime. It always returns me the same time in `GMT`.

All I see is that everyone is suggesting to use `Timezone`, i.e,

```
dateFormatter.setTimezone("any_arbitary_timezone");
```

Point is my application will be used in different geographical locations. I cannot set it to a particular timezone. It should be set to the system timezone, so that it can display in whichever timezone the user is currently in.

Comment: The time is in your local system time. Are you sure your machine isn't set to GMT?

Comment: Yes. using an Ubuntu machine. Its set to Asia/ Kolkatta.. IST

Comment: If your pc is really set to that timezone (`IST`), then somewhere in your application the timezone is set to `GMT` programatically.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Thats exactly what had happened. It was due to one of the env.sh file where timezone was set to GMT.  Ref: -Duser.timezone=GMT

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way to get the id of a `TimeZone` that matches your local system clock's offset,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long milliDiff = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
// Got local offset, now loop through available timezone id(s).
String [] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
String name = null;
for (String id : ids) {
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
  if (tz.getRawOffset() == milliDiff) {
    // Found a match.
    name = id;
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: It gives the first name that matches. On my pc, it should be `Eastern Standard Time` but it returns `America/Atikokan`.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes. Same here. However, it is in Eastern Time and it is not GMT.

Comment: @KiranKulkarni looks like your pc isn't set in `IST` . Check the timezone [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and African is the same as `GMT` (0 offset)

Comment: On terminal it shows this:-

$ date
Thu Jul 17 20:29:19 IST 2014....

But its somehow wierd my jvm is set to GMT

Comment: Found out that there was some shell script file in my tomcat which was setting -Duser.timezone=GMT. 

Im accepting your answer.

If anyone is interestd. Here s the link for my issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565052/how-can-i-change-default-timezone-in-liferay-portal-5-2

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I normally hates these answers. I am certain there must be a simple function to do this.

Answer (score 95):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(           // Capture the current moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.systemDefault()   // Get the JVM’s current default time zone. Can change at any moment during runtime. If important, confirm with the user.
)                            // Renders a `ZonedDateTime` object. To see the same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant` object by calling `ZonedDateTime::getInstant`.
```

You may omit the explicit call to `ZoneId.systemDefault`. (But I do not recommend this.)

```
ZonedDateTime.now()          // Capture the current moment in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Parse your string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), and adjust into desired time zone.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00" )    // Parse a string lacking any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. *Not* a specific point on the timeline.
             .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )           // Apply UTC as we are certain that offset-from-UTC of zero was intended by the supplier of that input string. Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
             .atZoneSameInstant(                   // Adjust into another time zone. The `sameInstant` part means the same moment, different wall-clock time. 
                 ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )       // Specify the particular zone of interest to you.
             )                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## Avoid `java.util.Date` & `.Calendar`

These legacy classes are notoriously troublesome. Sun/Oracle added the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package in Java 8 to supplant them. That package was inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Amongst the legacy classes’ problems is this confusing behavior: While a java.util.Date has no time zone information, it's `toString` implementation applies the JVM’s current default time zone when generating a String. So it misleads you by seeming to have a time zone when it does not.

## java.time

> I am trying to convert this string "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00", …

Your input string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), which lacks any concept of zone/offset.

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. The word “Local” here does *not* mean a specific locality. It means “no specific locality at all”. Without the context of a zone/offset, it has no real meaning.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00" ) ;
```

> … which is in GMT …

You say you are certain the supplier of that input string intended UTC as the context. We can apply an offset-from-UTC of zero, or UTC itself, to get an `OffsetDateTime` object. An `OffsetDateTime` *is* a moment, a point on the timeline. We can specify the `ZoneOffset` using the constant for UTC, [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> … to my timezone datetime

Apparently you want to adjust that moment into another time zone, to see the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region. We need to apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Instead of specifying a time zone, you can ask your JVM for its current default time zone. Beware: The JVM’s current default time zone can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within that JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> Point is my application will be used in different geographical locations.

Simply specify your desired/expected time zones explicitly. This is *always* good practice, in my opinion. The default time zone lies outside your control as a programmer, which makes it unreliable.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Another tip: Work, think, store, and exchange in UTC. Forget about your own parochial time zone, as translating back-and-forth to your home zone will drive you batty. Think of UTC as the *One True Time*, and other zones/offsets are but mere variations.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.

ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = instant.atZone( zAuckland ) ;

ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( zKolkata ) ;

ZoneId zCasablanca = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtCasablanca = instant.atZone( zCasablanca ) ;
```

There we have four ways ( `instant`, `zdtAuckland`, `zdtKolkata`, `zdtCasablanca` ) of looking at the very same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline.

> instant.toString(): 2018-05-08T20:55:14.761721Z

> zdtAuckland.toString(): 2018-05-09T08:55:14.761721+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

> zdtKolkata.toString(): 2018-05-09T02:25:14.761721+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

> zdtCasablanca.toString(): 2018-05-08T21:55:14.761721+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]

## Zone vs Offset

An offset-from-UTC is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds. Nothing more, nothing less. Any number of time zones may share a particular offset at a particular moment.

A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. For example, Daylight Saving Time (DST) is a practice where the people of a region (inexplicably) decide to change their offset twice a year.

So a time zone is always preferable to a mere offset. Having a zone allows us to add or subtract time in a meaningful way, to account for changes in offset in that region’s history.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. Skip to java.time section below in this Answer.

The Joda-Time package has good clear support for time zones. Unlike java.util.Date, a Joda-Time DateTime does know its own assigned time zone. If you fail to specify a time zone, the JVM's current default time zone is implicitly assigned.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now(); // Applies JVM’s default time zone implicitly.
```

I recommend against relying on the default time zone implicitly. Doing so leads to confusion and errors when doing date-time work.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() ); // Explicitly using default time zone.
```

If needed you may assign a time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ); // Specify a time zone.
```

For server-side work, best practice is to do business logic and database storage in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Assign UTC (GMT) time zone.
```

You can convert from the assigned time zone to another, including the JVM's current default time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeUtc.withZone( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```

### Immutable

For thread-safety, Joda-Time uses [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Instead of modifying an object, methods such as `withZone` create a new instance based on the original.

### Parse String

To parse a String as a DateTime, you must note whether the String includes an offset from UTC and/or a time zone. Yours does not. So you must specify a time zone by which to interpret that String. If you do not specify, the JVM’s current default time zone will be used during parsing.

In your Question, you said the String represents a date-time in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ([GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)).

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

After parsing, you may assign another time zone if needed. Same moment in the time-line of the Universe, but shows a different [Wall-Clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
DateTime dateTimeDefaultZone = dateTimeUtc.withZone( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```

So notice this was a two-step process. First we parsed your String using our external knowledge of that String's intended time zone because it lacked internal representation of that time zone or offset. Secondly we adjusted the time zone to another (the JVM default zone).

If your String had included an offset of `+00:00` or the customary `Z`, we could have collapsed those two steps into one.

```
DateTime dateTimeDefaultZone = new DateTime(  "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00Z", DateTimeZone.getDefault() ); // Apply time zone adjustment *after* parsing.
```

Note that this DateTime constructor looks like the one above but is actually quite different. This one's time zone argument is applied *after* parsing, rather than *during* parsing. Here the time zone argument is used to adjust the already-parsed DateTime. That `Z` on the end makes a world of difference.

## Source of Default Time Zone

The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) initially gets its default time zone from the host operating system. But be aware that a programmer can override this by:

- Pass an argument on command-line when launching the JVM.
- Call [`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-).

Doing this override affects all threads of all apps running in that JVM. So you should know that the JVM’s default time zone is usually the same as host OS but not necessarily the same.

Comment: What an awesome write up! Worked liked a charm.

Comment: Wow, what a thorough answer, a true guide to date and time API in Java. Thanks!

Comment: Works flawlessly! e.g. LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T07:00:00").atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();

Answer (score 1):

```
      private String receivedFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", expectedFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; //Globall variables

        //Write these three lines in your Test Class and below 2 methods

        String dateString = "2018-08-14T07:00:00:00";
        String returnString = correctDateFormat(dateString, receivedFormat, expectedFormat);
        String result = getTimeInSelectedLocale(returnString);
    Log.i("Ayaz", "Date: " +result);



     /**
         * @param receivedDate
         * @param givenFormat
         * @param expectedFormat
         * @return returns date time in expected format
         */
        public static String correctDateFormat(String receivedDate, String givenFormat, String expectedFormat) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(receivedDate)) {
                return "";
            }
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(givenFormat);
            Date newDate = null;
            try {
                newDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(receivedDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat);
            receivedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(newDate);
            return receivedDate;
        }



        /**
         * @param dateString
         * @return passed string date in different locale, My Db is in IST so I an converting IST in different locale
         */
        public  String getTimeInSelectedLocale(String dateString) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString)) {
                return dateString;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")); //We want Indian time to change in different locale, so this line is compulsory, you can replace with your country
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = sdf.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //below this line -> TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID(), will return current locale for example for India "Asia/Kolkata" for UAE "Asia/Dubai"
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())); //This line chooses current local in which you want time
            String localDate = sdf.format(date1);
            return localDate;
        }

//I am converting the IST time "2018-08-14T07:00:00:00"  into UAE(Duabai) "14-08-2018 05:30:00" and other countries
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) library.  It has functionality better than the Calendar or Date classes as specified in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010284/equivalent-of-cs-datetime-now-in-java).

[This function](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#LocalDateTime(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) should be particularly useful.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).