# How can I get operating system Time zone in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

The TimeZone.getDefault() returns the System Time zone until it's changed.

Sample 1:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Result:

```
Europe/Kaliningrad
```

It is system time zone.

Sample 2:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Result:

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

It isn't system time zone, system time zone is still Europe/Kaliningrad.

So how can I get system time zone even after change default DateTimeZone.

Comment: the answer in previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806183/get-date-in-current-timezone-in-java

Comment: @user7294900, it returns Asia/Calcutta instead Europe/Kaliningrad

Comment: What are you expecting? When you call `setDefault`, it changes the default timezone for the whole JVM, **that's the expected behaviour**. If you don't want to change it, then don't call `setDefault` (or save the timezone in a variable before changing the default, as already suggested in the answers below).

Comment: @Hugo, I want to get System Time Zone (which is set for the operating system) regardless of which time zone is set on JVM.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/time-zone.html

Answer (score 3):

You can check system property user.timezone:

```
   System.getProperty("user.timezone")
```

Comment: it returns empty string for me.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of TimeZone.getDefault() in a variable before following codes

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

and use the variable later.

Comment: I hope that there is more beautiful solution.

Comment: @Evgenia TimeZone.setDefault overrides the system timezone so storing system timezone in a variable seems the good alternative.